# Until yesterday, I didn't know today "is" or "was"

Tags: grammar, auxiliary-verbs

Until yesterday, I didn't know today is Christmas day.

Or,

Until yesterday, I didn't know today was Christmas day.

Comment: Both are ok in my books. '[T[hat today was Christmas day' works because you are talking about the point where you realized this in the past. '[T]hat today is Christmas day is ok because it still is Christmas day at the moment of speaking.

Answer (score -1):

Until yesterday, I didn't know today is Christmas day. Or,

Until yesterday, I didn't know today was Christmas day.

---

Sorry Both are incorrect Try

Until yesterday, I did not know today would be Christmas day

It was in the past when you realised Christmas day would be today, in the future/ However it is an awkward way to say it and does not sound good.

**Only Yesterday, I realised today would be Christmas** or **Until yesterday, I had forgotten today would be Christmas.**

---

**would** modal verb (FUTURE) [C.E. Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/would) used to refer to future time from the point of view of the past:

Comment: Don't understand the downvote. Obviously this is the "right" answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you. That is not the first time that comment has been made and I am sure it will not be the last. The annoying part is they never comment. If I am wrong I can learn something, being a bit of a cynic I am beginning to think they are done maliciously.  Ah! I am getting paranoid it's only a website not R.L.

Comment: Well, in practice native speakers will often use Simple Past ***was*** in such context. I find it interesting that (to me, at least) the chances of using ***was*** rather than ***would be*** seem to be affected by the *exact* nature of the "previously unknown future situation, *which is now known*". Specifically, we *must* use the modal auxiliary form with *Until you told me last night, I didn't know today **would be** overcast*. And for me, ***...would be a bank holiday*** works better than ***...would be your birthday*** (I think because the latter sounds more "fixed, knowable in advance").

Comment: nearly posted the wrong comment then. Your correct, however Native speakers tend to use less formal sentences so it alters the equation somewhat. Just last night I realised it was Christmas"  Not correct grammatically or an exact explanation but everyone understands it's meaning.

Comment: Gotta maintain standards here! That's *...everyone understands **its meaning***, or maybe *...understands [that] **it's meaningful*** :)